# Adding BigDecimal.ZERO to another BigDecimal value

Tags: java

I'm still learning Java, and I've been reading articles on several sites. I found an article at [Java Code Geeks](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2018/02/solid-principles-open-closed-principle.html/) that I have a question about. The article is explaining open/closed principle. The article uses a scenario of applying a discount to a company's product for it's example. The first part of the code is as follows:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class Discount {

    public BigDecimal apply(BigDecimal price) {

        BigDecimal percent = new BigDecimal("0.10");
        BigDecimal discount = price.multiply(percent);
        return price.subtract(discount.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    }
}
```

The second part of the code is as follows:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class DiscountService {

    public BigDecimal applyDiscounts(BigDecimal price,Discount discount) {

        BigDecimal discountPrice = price.add(BigDecimal.ZERO);
        discountPrice = discount.apply(discountPrice);
        return discountPrice;
   }
}
```

On Oracle's site, it says that the ZERO in BigDecimal has a a value of 0 and a scale of zero. Does this mean that in `price.add(BigDecimal.ZERO)` we are simply adding 0 to the price that's brought in? If so, why? Or is it there simply to drop the decimal places from the price? Or is there some other purpose for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`price.add(BigDecimal.ZERO)` is being used to create a new `BigDecimal` since `BigDecimal` doesn't have a copy constructor.

As to why, this is presumably a defensive copy in case the `BigDecimal` being passed in is actually a "sabotaged" version (because `BigDecimal` isn't `final`) whose value can be changed after the fact.  This is talked about in depth in Effective Java as the item "Make defensive copies when needed;" Item 39 in 2nd edition or Item 50 in 3rd Edition.

Comment: @David: Makes sense what Pwerlord is saying, but if are still curious then best is to put a comment on the article and if you can get lucky and author replies.

Comment: @Powerlord Hmm, that seems to be what they are doing, but it's still pretty strange because even if it were sabotaged, `SabotagedBigDecimal.add(BigDecimal bd)` could've been overridden to return `this`.

Comment: @xtratic That's actually a good point.  They should have done `BigDecimal.ZERO.add(price)` which would return a standard `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @Powerlord I think the consensus here is that `bigDecimal.add(BigDecimal.ZERO)` is pointless and confusing, not expressing the true intent.

Comment: `bigDecimal.add(BigDecimal.ZERO)` would be a little too ambiguous.

Comment: @xtratic Whoops, forgot about this thread.  Yeah, either way isn't going to express the true intent.  I have no idea why `BigDecimal` doesn't have a copy constructor for this express purpose.

Comment: @Powerlord It'd certainly be nice if it did.

Comment: @Taslim Exactly `bigDecimal.add(BigDecimal.ZERO)` doesn't express that the intent is just to make a defensive copy. (hence why it confused OP)